Magento 2 - Could not find package magento/project-enterprise-edition with version 2.4.4-p3
I had an issue as below
Could not find package magento/project-enterprise-edition with version 2.4.4-p3
Which happen when I run below command to install the fresh project
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition=2.4.4-p3 magento2-commerce
I have try many fix as below which does not able to fix the issue

Running composer config --global http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key> and put in newly created public_key and private_key
Check if there is any problem with composer by running composer clear-cache, unable to find any problem with composer, composer version used is 2.5.1
Create auth.json at /home/user/.composer/auth.json and put in content as below
.

    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<public_key>",
            "password": "<private_key>"
        }
    }
}


Check and update the content at /home/user/.config/composer/auth.json as I think the path above might be incorrect
Remove the auth.json
Find any auth.json file using find / -type f -iname auth.json

Do I have to create my own composer.json and then run composer install, if yes what do I need to write into the composer.json
Appreciate any kind of help , thank you
